# Why near the UTC TIME 5:00 appears spam questions?

Tags: discussion, spam

I have seen that normally near the UTC TIME 5:00 appears spam questions, Why? Normally in other sites of the network I don't see this behavior. And usually there are two questions. The moderators have any tool to detect if the question comes from the same IP to block it?

Comment: There are always spam on Drupal.SE. It's time-agnostic.